# SuperClass And subclasses

Tags: java

Hi I am relatively new to programming and I am studying inhertance at the moment.

There is an exmaple in a book that has a class which does not extend any other class(So is it fair to say this is the superclass) also there is another class which extends this class. But what I really cant get is the class which does not extend any other class contains @Override. I thought @Override was only used in subclasses to override the superclass.

Any help would be really appreciated

Comment: _"In the absence of any other explicit superclass, every class is implicitly a subclass of Object."_ So it certainly overrides the method herited from the Object class.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The only class which does not extend any other class is `Object`. All other classes derive from it either directly or indirectly.

Your example with a class "which doesn't extend any other" looks something like this:

```
public class MyStuff {
   @Override public String toString() { return "MyStuff here"; }
}
```

In the above, `extends Object` is implied if not written. Therefore you should read it as

```
public class MyStuff extends Object { ... }
```

There are just three public methods in `Object` which it makes sense to override: `toString`, `equals`, and `hashCode`, so I assume your example uses one (ore more) of these.

Answer (score 2):

In java `Object` class is the super class of all classes. So @`Override` method must be belongs to Object class methods.